# For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, given that $A^2=A, A\neq I$, show that $\det A=0$

Tags: matrices

For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, given that $A^2=A, A\neq I$, show that $\det A=0.$

I'm not sure how to begin on showing this - does anyone have any pointers on how to begin? I tried creating a generic matrix with elements a to i then squaring it, but solving and showing equality for the two matrices seems far too difficult and tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** If $\det(A) \neq 0$ then $A$ is invertible. Multiply your relation by $A^{-1}$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $A(A-I)=0$, $A\neq I$ implies $A-I\neq 0$, $\operatorname{Im}(A-I)\subset \ker(A)$ and $A$ is not injective implies $\det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

From $A(A-I)=0$, since $A-I\ne0$, you have that $A$ cannot be invertible (if it were, you could multiply by $A^{-1}$ on the left to get $A-I=0$).